# XCode 4.2 - can't build to a device

Tags: xcode4.2

I just updated my xcode to 4.2 and also my device to ios 5.
Now that I've done that, I can't seem to be able to compile to my device.
When I select compile to iOS device, in the previous XCode version, there used to be my device iOS version next to it but it's not there now.

Also compiling, gives me this error.
"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

Am I missing a step here? (I checked that my device does have the provisioning profile and base sdk is set to 5.0)

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, need to re-register the device for development.
It got wiped out. organizer -> device

Comment: I can't believe the error message for this is so unintuitive :( What a waste of time ... but thanks for posting this answer :)