# Xcode 4.2 running slow after importing iOS 5.1 SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

After solving this problem: [Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.0 not detecting iPhone iOS 5.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451304/xcode-4-2-with-ios-5-0-not-detecting-iphone-ios-5-1-1) I unfortunatelly found myself with Xcode running so slow, that even scrolling viewports is taking few minutes, not to mention that building on device is taking like 5 minutes insted of 10 seconds... Does anyone know if and how to solve such a problem?

Comment: check if it is doing a documentation download (preferences --> downloads) these can be killers and take forever.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Xcode 4.2 try to use Xcode 4.2.3 the latest version.Because it is lighter than the previous version.And Please use minimum 4GB of RAM for smooth run.